# what is the difference between ows_q and ows_q_text

Tags: content-search-web-part, search-query

When I try to create a managed property in Search and I try to select a crawled property, I get two sort of crawled properties for the same site column.

```
ows_q_TDC_x0020_Article_x0020_Number
```

and

```
ows_q_TEXT_TDCArticleNumber
```

OK, I understand the last one which contains TEXT in it show the type of the field, but what is the difference between them and which one do I have to choose?

I am asking this because I am getting a big headache from the managed properties when I try to use them in the Content Search Web part. I am always getting the following error when I try to use the managed property in the Sorting Tab in Build your Query window:

```
Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.
```

This what I have done when I created the managed property:

1. Mapped crawled Property to a Managed Property
2. Specified "Sortable","Refinable", etc
3. Performed a full crawl
4. tried to use it in Content Search Query "sorting", but here I get the error above.

I try to use it in my code like this:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'TDCArticleNumber':'TDCArticleNumber'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>

_#= ctx.CurrentItem.TDCArticleNumber =#_
```

but this gives nothing back, even though there is content.

Any help please? It is making me nuts.

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have same problem

Answer (score 1):

Difference will be in sorting search results.

Example if you have a date field and you want to sort on this date.
If the type of the managed property is 'Text' the search results will not sort correctly. If the type is 'DateTime' the sorting will work as expected.

In regards to your error you can try this:

- The managed property has the option 'Queryable' set to true
- (optional) set managed property option 'Retrievable' to true.
- Make sure the scope of your search is correct
- That you have documents with the property filled out

To be sure do a full crawl after the changes.

Comment: I have already done all of the above. I think scopes are gone in SP 2013 search. 

However, your explanation does not really answer my question above about the difference between `ows_q_TDC_x0020_Article_x0020_Number` and `ows_q_TEXT_TDCArticleNumber`. These two crawled properties refer to the same field which is of data type "Text". I am not talking about two different fields with different data type.